# Is there a way to hide a password in a scheduler in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a job that calls a program.  This program executes a shell script that ftp files to a different server.  In the program I pass in the arguments user, password and IP address.  Is there anyway to hide these arguments.  I am using oracle 11g.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could FTP from within Oracle using PL/SQL. An example [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql.php).

I don't know of a way to hide or secure the password for the external FTP client, but the correct way to deal with this would probably be to use SFTP instead of FTP, and a private/public key pair for authentication.

I found [this guide](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) on key generation.